# How to find out the size of a mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, command

So, for example, if there's a mercurial repository https://code.google.com/p/potentiallyLarge is there a command which would allow me to find out its size before cloning it?  Something like

```
hg size https://code.google.com/p/potentiallyLarge
```

Also, is there a command for doing this for subversion repositories?

Comment: I'm very interested in the answer to this for SVN, as I'm looking at having to clone a 10+GB SVN repo (determined by svn list -R) with >10000 revisions using Mercurial (hgsubversion) across the internet.

Comment: @TimDelaney in you case you're probably better off using `svnsync` and then cloning from that repository locally.  Just a guess though.

Comment: @Ry4an I've thought about doing that (then changing the URL to the upstream SVN). The disadvantage is doubling the storage space (at least temporarily). Plus I have no idea if I'll get any advantage in total data transferred. I'm setting up an Hg repo for local devs with 2-way syncing. Got the workflow determined and tested to allow everyone to work as you would normally for Hg (branch, merge, etc) with some hooks to prevent accidental breakage of the workflow (no merges to SVN branch ...). It's just going to be that initial clone that'll be a pain - do I get everything, or just a subset?

Comment: I don't use hgsubversion, but I imagine its clone gets everything.  The advantage of svnsync over the clone is that it's resumeable, whereas if the big initial clone fails you're stuck.

Comment: No - that's not a problem - you can pull up to a certain revision, etc. Of course, if a single revision is too big, it's a problem, which an argument for pulling the entire history (if you just pull HEAD, it'll be like doing an SVN checkout from scratch ...).

Answer (score 4):

The size used on disk is different from the bandwidth used to make a clone. Some hosting sites (such as Bitbucket) display the size on disk so that you know upfront how much space you'll need on your system before cloning. But I can see that Google Code doesn't, so it wont help you here.

The Mercurial [wire protocol](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WireProtocol) doesn't expose any commands that can tell you how big a repository is. When you make a normal clone, the client doesn't know upfront how much data it will receive, it just receives a stream of data. After receiving the changelog, the client knows *how many* manifests and filelogs to expect, but it doesn't know the *size* of them.

In fact, it's difficult for the server to compute how much data a clone will use: the network bandwidth used is less than the disk space since the compression used is different (bzip2 vs gzip). However, if you use `--uncompressed` with your clone (which Google Code doesn't support) then there is a trick, see below.

The only way to know much bandwidth a clone uses is to make one. If you have a clone already you can use `hg bundle` to simulate a clone:

```
$ hg bundle --all my-bundle.hg
```

The size of the bundle will tell you how much data there is in the repository.

**A trick:** If Google Code had supported `hg clone --uncompressed`, then you could use that to learn the size of a remote repository! When you use `--uncompressed`, the client asks the server to send the content of the `.hg/` directory as-is — without re-compressing it with bzip2. Conveniently, the server starts the stream by telling the client **the size of the repository**. So you can start such a clone and then abort it (with Control-C) when your client has printed the line telling you the size of the repo.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** My answer below is wrong, but I'm leaving it here since MG provided some good info in response.  It looks like the right answer is "no".

Not a great way, but a work-around sort of way.  A `hg clone URL` is really just `hg init ; hg pull URL`  And the command `hg incoming` tells you what you'd get if you did a pull, so you could do:

```
hg init theproject
cd theproject
hg incoming --stat URL_TO_THE_PROJECT
```

and get a pretty decent guess of how much data you'll be pulling down if you follow up with:

```
hg pull URL_TO_THE_PROJECT
```

I'm not sure about the network efficiency of `hg incoming` but I don't think it downloads everything from all the changesets, though I could be wrong about that.  It offers a `--bundle` option that saves whatever incoming pulls down to a file from which you can later pull to avoid double downloading.

Comment: The incoming command **will download everything** since there's no way for a client to say "please give me the changelog for this or that changeset".

Comment: Blast, I was hoping it could download "headers" but not the real "deltas".

Comment: Yeah, that's what you would expect from the output... but unfortunately it cannot do this today.